# How to install DC++ on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I can't find DC++ in the software center. But I remember using it in an earlier Ubuntu version. Is there a way to install it on 14.04 other than using wine?

Comment: Try an alternative: [EiskaltDC++](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/eiskaltdcpp-qt/), [Valknut](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/valknut/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinuxDC++ is the Linux port of DC++ and is available in the Ubuntu Software Center on 14.04. You don't need wine for it.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need wine here.

use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install linuxdcpp
```

to install linux dc++